# Cannot access an array of clipping planes stored in a single UBO OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, indexing, glsl, clipping

As described in OpenGL Vertex Post-Processing https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Post-Processing Under User-defined Clipping, I am trying to clip each vertex send to a plane in the vertex shader. Providing only an index per vertex, so that I can access the UBO's data, which contains the clipping plane information, determined and send before the actual BIG data push.

"...It is possible to mitigate this by using a UBO to store an array of clipping regions, with each vertex simply specifying an integer index into that array...."

The problem is that somehow I cannot access the UBO with a simple indexing, because the clip index buffer sent along just refuses to work, although the data is full and correct. (Inspected in NSight).

The GPU simply thinks that I want to access only the first clipping rect.
(ClipIndex is always equal to ZERO);
So it only works for the first window in my simple imgui.

So I have heard of OpenGL not accepting indexing since version 1.2 or something. Is this the reason??? They have even set a hard restriction on the size of the UBO (I think 6kb). What then is the specific reason why I cannot access my data? I can fetch a texel from wherever I want in a texture, but I cannot get some simple data with a constant size buffer.

It compiles clean, I have checked for errors and validated the program.
Also links fine. If I hard set it into the vertex shader it works fine.
Meaning that if I want to clip only for window one (Clip.Rects[1]) no problem.
When I introduce a single contiguous array of indices, we are out of the game. The array is always treated as if it is full with ZEROs.

I know the code may not be optimal. For now we are trying to reach the working phase.

I am new to asking questions here, so please don't hate me for the wrong indentation of the code.

The alternatives, in my opinion, are to draw 6 or less verts per rectangle and each time I have to clip to a different plane do it manually changing the glScissor() or glClipPlane(). 
And the second one, which comes to mind, is to use a texture to store the data, which I don't like, because it is not a texture :D.

Why my approach is busted? And are there better ways to clip one contiguous array of vertex data to multiple planes?

```
   #version 400 core
   struct rect 
   {
    float X;
    float Y;
    float Width;
    float Height;
   };

   layout (shared) uniform clip_rects
   {
    rect Rects[50];
   } Clip;

   out float gl_ClipDistance[6]; // Clipping each vert to a rectangle plane

   // Skippied some unrelated info colors depth...
   in vec2 RectVBO;
   in int ClipIndex;

   uniform mat4 PCMatrix;

   void main()
   {
         gl_Position = PCMatrix * vec4(RectVBO.xy, Depth, 1.0f);

         //FIRST ATTEMPT (already in -1,1 space)
     vec2 v0 = vec2(Clip.Rects[ClipIndex].X, Clip.Rects[ClipIndex].Y);
     vec2 v1 = vec2(Clip.Rects[ClipIndex].X + Clip.Rects[ClipIndex].Width, Clip.Rects[ClipIndex].Y);
     vec2 v2 = vec2(Clip.Rects[ClipIndex].X + Clip.Rects[ClipIndex].Width, Clip.Rects[ClipIndex].Y + Clip.Rects[ClipIndex].Height);
     vec2 v3 = vec2(Clip.Rects[ClipIndex].X, Clip.Rects[ClipIndex].Y + Clip.Rects[ClipIndex].Height);
         //END OF FIRST ATTEMPT

         //Even this doesn't work!
         //SECOND ATTEMPT

         vec2 v0 = vec2(0.0f,0.0f);
     vec2 v1 = vec2(0.0f,0.0f);
     vec2 v2 = vec2(0.0f,0.0f);
     vec2 v3 = vec2(0.0f,0.0f);
         //NOTE: It only takes the first if block if we set it to 1, 2, 3
         //for example its all set to the above zeroed out vec2s.
         if(ClipIndex == 0)
     {
    v0 = vec2(Clip.Rects[0].X, Clip.Rects[0].Y);
    v1 = vec2(Clip.Rects[0].X + Clip.Rects[0].Width, Clip.Rects[0].Y);
    v2 = vec2(Clip.Rects[0].X + Clip.Rects[0].Width, Clip.Rects[0].Y + Clip.Rects[0].Height);
    v3 = vec2(Clip.Rects[0].X, Clip.Rects[0].Y + Clip.Rects[0].Height);
     }
     else if(ClipIndex == 1)
     {
    v0 = vec2(Clip.Rects[1].X, Clip.Rects[1].Y);
    v1 = vec2(Clip.Rects[1].X + Clip.Rects[1].Width, Clip.Rects[1].Y);
    v2 = vec2(Clip.Rects[1].X + Clip.Rects[1].Width, Clip.Rects[1].Y + Clip.Rects[1].Height);
    v3 = vec2(Clip.Rects[1].X, Clip.Rects[1].Y + Clip.Rects[1].Height);
    } else if(ClipIndex == 2)
    {
    v0 = vec2(Clip.Rects[2].X, Clip.Rects[2].Y);
    v1 = vec2(Clip.Rects[2].X + Clip.Rects[2].Width, Clip.Rects[2].Y);
    v2 = vec2(Clip.Rects[2].X + Clip.Rects[2].Width, Clip.Rects[2].Y + Clip.Rects[2].Height);
    v3 = vec2(Clip.Rects[2].X, Clip.Rects[2].Y + Clip.Rects[2].Height);
    }

         // END OF SECOND ATTEMPT

         //Tried "local" variable indexing still no progress.
        //THIRD ATTEMPT
vec2 v0 = vec2(0.0f,0.0f);
vec2 v1 = vec2(0.0f,0.0f);
vec2 v2 = vec2(0.0f,0.0f);
vec2 v3 = vec2(0.0f,0.0f);

for(int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
{
    if(k == ClipIndex)
    {
        v0 = vec2(Clip.Rects[k].X, Clip.Rects[k].Y);
        v1 = vec2(Clip.Rects[k].X + Clip.Rects[k].Width, Clip.Rects[k].Y);
        v2 = vec2(Clip.Rects[k].X + Clip.Rects[k].Width, Clip.Rects[k].Y + Clip.Rects[k].Height);
        v3 = vec2(Clip.Rects[k].X, Clip.Rects[k].Y + Clip.Rects[k].Height);
    }
}
         //END OF THIRD ATTEMPT

     vec2 VecToVertex0 = gl_Position.xy - v0;
     vec2 VecToVertex1 = gl_Position.xy - v1;
     vec2 VecToVertex2 = gl_Position.xy - v2;
     vec2 VecToVertex3 = gl_Position.xy - v3;

     vec2 v0v1 = v1 - v0;
     vec2 v1v2 = v2 - v1;
     vec2 v2v0 = v0 - v2;

     vec2 v0v2 = v2 - v0;
     vec2 v2v3 = v3 - v2;
     vec2 v3v0 = v0 - v3;

     gl_ClipDistance[0] = dot(v0v1, VecToVertex0);
     gl_ClipDistance[1] = dot(v1v2, VecToVertex1);
     gl_ClipDistance[2] = dot(v2v0, VecToVertex2);

     gl_ClipDistance[3] = dot(v0v2, VecToVertex0);
     gl_ClipDistance[4] = dot(v2v3, VecToVertex2);
     gl_ClipDistance[5] = dot(v3v0, VecToVertex3);


     }
```

Comment: I suspect of `ClipIndex` which is an integer in the GLSL code. If you pass it at C++ code by using `glUniform1f` then that is wrong. You must use `glUniform1i` (note the 'i' at the end)

Comment: `in int ClipIndex;`. I'd make the [same guess as here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55908848/2327517).